# Outlook 2007 - Internet Security warning (Certificate error)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, internet-explorer-8

I have a user running still running on Windows XP + Outlook 2007. He uses a google apps email account through IMAP w/ SSL on port 993

Recently he's started receiving an error message shown here.
 [image: Error Message]
[image: Certificate Error message]

The time on this computer is properly set and all updates have been installed (include the optional root certification updates)

https website work without a problem it's really only outlook that is seeing this error. Doing a lot of searching on google before posting I also came across some people saying to clear the SSL state in Internet Explorer under Internet Options -> Content -> Clear SSL state and I've also reset the internet Explorer settings as well.

Would anyone here suggest any additional troubleshooting to try to get this error "silenced" at the very least?

Comment: The date on the certificate, is that to 4th August 2014, or to 8th April 2014?

Comment: @BigChris that's August 4th

Comment: Is the outgoing mail server address correct? instead of "imap.example.com" should it be "smtp.example.com"?

Comment: @BigChris I believe we are getting the cert error on the incoming imap.gmail.com and not the outgoing

Comment: And you've gone through the GMail's official instructions to adding an IMAP account to Outlook? (have to ask to rule out something stupid!)

Comment: @BigChris Yes followed the official instructions from google. I've also tested on other computers and that worked fine. I have not been able to test it on another XP computer though as this is the only one I have left.

Comment: Are there any firewall software on the computer blocking port 993?

Comment: @BigChris I've disabled the Firewall on this computer so we can rule out the firewall. An interesting thing to keep in mind is that I added another imap email account using the same port (993) and SSL but from a different provider (our in house server w/ a valid SSL cert) and it worked flawlessly. What are the chances that this has something to do with windows XP solely?

Answer (score 1):

Open Outlook > Click ‘Tools’ from the top menu > Select ‘account settings’ from the ‘tools’ menu > Highlight the email account you are having trouble with and press ‘Change’ > From the ‘Change e-mail account’ page click on ‘More settings’ >From the ‘Internet email settings’ page choose the ‘advanced’ tab >Un-tick the ‘This server requires authentication’ option > click ‘OK’, then ‘next’ then ‘Finish’

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of troubleshooting this issue I ended up upgrading this user to the latest version of office (2013). This appear to have fixed the certificate error they were receiving.

Hope this ends up helping someone else in the future and saving them endless hours troubleshooting!